# simple program using jacob and excel

Tags: java, excel, jacob

i want to learn [jacob](http://danadler.com/jacob/) for doing tasks with excel. looking for any simple code using jacob and excel which runs without errors. i tried running the code in jacob help but i'm getting errors. to understand the basics i need a simple code. Can you provide me this sample code .thanks

Comment: Did you read the website you reference?  Can you post samples of what you tried and what didn't work?  You're much more likely to get help if you show some evidence of wanting to learn instead of just asking for someone to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would help if you posted the errors and what exactly you are trying to do.

Is there any reason you would not use Apache POI http://poi.apache.org/

In either case I found it was helpful to do the work in VB first and then make the calls with JACOB because you can them map across easily

Comment: From what I can tell POI does not allow for automation.